3d sliding images issue
enter image description here
Hello i have this html and css code. currently it got 8 images sliding 360 degree i want to have another 8 images but showing in the back instead of the same image reflected. I provided two blocks of code first HTML second CSS. Thansk in advance!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- === style sheet ====  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>3D Image Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <span style="--i:1;"><img src="images/img1.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i:2;"><img src="images/img2.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i:3;"><img src="images/img3.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i:4;"><img src="images/img4.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i:5;"><img src="images/img5.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i:6;"><img src="images/img6.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i:7;"><img src="images/img7.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:8;"><img src="images/img8.png"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c5364, #0f2027);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rotate 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

.slider span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(350px);
}


.slider span img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: 2s;
}

.slider span:hover img {
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(1.2);
}

i want to have another 8 images but showing in the back instead of the same image reflected. I provided two blocks of code first HTML second CSS. Thansk in advance!

Please show us what you have tried in order to achieve this, and describe in what way it isn't working. (We are happy to help debug your own code, but not to write it ab initio for you).
